# Qual a tradução técnica para "welding", "soldering" e "brazing"?

Tags: tradução-inglês

Os termos anglófonos "welding", "soldering" e "brazing" são amiúde traduzidos para Português, apenas usando a expressão *soldadura*.[[1]](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/ingles-portugues/welding)[[2]](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/ingles-portugues/soldering)[[3]](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/ingles-portugues/brazing) Todavia tecnicamente, estes métodos são bem distintos.

Em "welding", os metais têm deformação termoplástica semelhante, ou seja, os próprios metais precisam de ter características semelhantes, e existe uma fusão entre si, através de temperaturas muito elevadas, para cima dos 5000 graus Celsius. Logo, ao fundirem-se ("derreterem-se"), as peças mesclam-se e o resultado final torna a resistência da união equivalente como se de uma peça única se tratasse. Este método permite obter a união mais forte e resistente das três mencionadas.

Em "soldering" e "brazing" faz-se uso de temperaturas bem mais baixas, com o auxílio de um elemento externo unificador, normalmente denominado de solda, que após ficar liquefeito e arrefecido, une as duas peças. "Soldering" está adaptado para uma boa ligação elétrica, enquanto "brazing" para uma boa ligação mecânica. Estes métodos, por fazerem uso de um elemento externo, permitem a união de metais diferentes. A diferença entre estes dois métodos está na temperatura e na solda, visto que "brazing" exige uma temperatura mais elevada devido à solda usada, considerando que "brazing" faz uso de soldas à base de ligas de estanho e chumbo, enquanto "soldering" mais à base de cobre.

A pergunta é pois: quais são as traduções técnicas rigorosas para Português destes três diferentes métodos de união de materiais?

Comment: Há uma incoerência: se brazing exige temperaturas mais elevadas, então é o brasing que faz uso de soldas à base de cobre e não o soldering. Isto, porque a temperatura para trabalhar com cobre é pelo menos 3 vezes maior do que para trabalhar com chumbo ou estanho. O soldering era um dos principais métodos para fazer as latas de comidas lá pelos anos 1900, usando o chumbo. Até hoje se usa a brasagem para união mecânica de peças, por exemplo em tubos mais delicados, com ponto de fusão acima do cobre, onde apenas a liga de cobre funde e se adere ao metal de base, dando firmeza ao conjunto.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Traduções que se encontram com frequência são:

- *Welding*: **soldagem**;
- *Brazing*: **brasagem (forte/dura)**;
- *Soldering*: **brasagem (fraca/mole/branda)**.

Existem diferentes graus de rigor e também nomenclaturas distintas em áreas distintas, mas as traduções acima parecem ser amplamente usadas.

Em particular, "soldar" pode ser usado num sentido amplo, não necessariamente técnico ([por exemplo](http://www.aulete.com.br/soldar), "A fratura soldou-se otimamente.") e não é incomum ver o termo "soldagem" usado no lugar de "brasagem" (como em "ferro de solda" [significando](https://www.linguee.pt/portugues-ingles/traducao/ferro+de+solda.html) *soldering iron*). Além disso, às vezes os termos em inglês são mantidos.

---

**Fontes**

[Soldagem - fundamentos e tecnologia](https://books.google.de/books?id=uIxCk9IcgJEC&lpg=PA342&ots=26jYWekFrU&dq=%22brasagem%20fraca%22&pg=PA335#v=onepage&q=%22brasagem%20fraca%22&f=false), por Modenesi et al., pg. 335:

> Se o ponto de fusão do metal de adição é superior a 450°C, o processo é dito "brasagem forte" ("brazing") e, em caso contrário, é dito "brasagem fraca" ("soldering").

[PMR-2202 – Introdução a Manufatura Mecânica](http://sites.poli.usp.br/d/pmr2202/arquivos/aulas/soldagem_brasagem.pdf), Prof. Dr. Gilmar Batalha, Escola Politécnica USP, outubro 2003:

> Os limites dos processos de brasagem são tomados conforme a temperatura de fusão do material de brasagem;
>
> - Até 450°C: brasagem mole (solda fraca)
> - A partir de 450°C: brasagem dura

[Glossário multilíngue](http://www.electropedia.org/iev/iev.nsf/display?openform&ievref=851-11-04) da International Electrotechnical Commission:

> **en**:   soft soldering
> soldering process using a molten filler material having a melting temperature lower than that of the parts to be joined and below 450°C
> **pt**:   brasagem fraca

[Infopedia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/brasagem):

> **brasagem**
> processo usado para unir duas ou mais peças metálicas através da utilização, como material de preenchimento, de um outro metal com um ponto de fusão inferior aos das peças metálicas que se pretende ligar

Vale notar que a temperatura que delimita os dois tipos mais comuns de brasagem é uma convenção e que o valor de 450 graus Celsius frequentemente citado é o adotado pela American Welding Society; outros valores também podem ser adotados, a se julgar pelo material de Lucas Berti (UTFPR), [PMM1/Aulas/Módulo 3/Aula 20](http://paginapessoal.utfpr.edu.br/lucasberti/pmm1/aulas/modulo-3/PMM%2020.pptx/view):

> Brasagem Fraca: a temperatura do metal de adição é menor que 600ºC, é utilizado o ferro de soldar como fonte de aquecimento. São conhecidos no comércio três tipos de brasagem fraca: Solda de bombeiro, Solda de rádio, Solda de funileiro.
>
> Brasagem Forte: na brasagem forte a temperatura do material de adição é superior a 600ºC. é usada um maçarico para a fonte de calor.

Comment: Muito obrigado, trabalho apenas em Inglês e convém estar ciente da terminologia portuguesa. Ademais providencou fontes académicas e credíveis.